# Редактирование текстового файла произвольного размера в C/C++

Tags: c, c++

Здравствуйте! Подскажите пожалуйста какую функцию нужно использовать? Перерыл наверно весь интернет и ничего не нашел. Например, файл [1.txt](http://1.txt) содержит информацию "12345z78" Как заменить символ 'z' на цифру '6'? В конце должно получиться "12345678".
Как правильно редактировать файл [1.txt](http://1.txt), не создавая другой файл? Пробовал функцию seekg() но он мне удаляет весь текст из файла перед тем как написать чтота в конкретной позиции.

Comment: Парсер - лох :)

Comment: Советую скачать хорошую книгу (какую ищите здесь или в гугле) по C\C++ и в первых главах описаны принципы работы с файлами, а именно получение содержимого, и обновление. А как вырезать char из char[] это уже работа со строками.

Comment: Не нужно никаких char. Все проще =) [fstream][1], [stringstream][2], [std::string][3]. Возможно даже не все из этого понадобится.

 [1]: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/fstream/
 [2]: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/
 [3]: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/

Comment: Используй функции для работы со строками.

Comment: @pol500 Обожаю такие емкие, полезные и насыщенные информацией комментарии :)

Comment: @Котик, как бэ студенты блещут своим на форумах :)

Comment: Либо пишите свой собственный редактор, либо вызывайте из С-шной программы какой-нибудь Блокнот или Word и правьте там. Самодельный редактор описан почти во всех руководствах в примерах по MDI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::fstream file("1.txt");

    if (!file.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "Error open file." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    file.seekp(5);
    file.write("6", 1);

    file.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Этот код сделает что ты хотел или я не понял твоего вопроса, ну а дальше сам уже читай доку по файловым потокам в С++.

Comment: а если эта буква z не 6-я по счету? seekp(5) то переместит на 6-ю, а если мы не знаем порядок?

Comment: Код делает то что просили в вопросе, ну а если хотите делать с блек джеком и шлюхами, то уточняйте вопрос. Можно считать строку проверить в ней символы на нужные вам и если какой-то надо заменить, заменяете и всё.

Comment: Надо еще инклюды сделать


    #include <fstream>
    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>

А то у ТС мозг порвет.

Comment: Спасибо тебе большое! Хоть один умный ответ, кстати мой код похож на твой но не работает

int main () {
ofstream outfile;
outfile.open ("1.txt");


  outfile.seekp (5);
  outfile.write ("6",1);

  outfile.close();

  return 0;
}

Comment: gecube > у меня с одним #include <fstream> все работает.
Feodor > Ты используешь ofstream этот поток дает только возможность считывать с файла.
к примеру ifstream дает тока запись в файл, а у меня использован двунаправленный поток fstream, с помощью которого можно и читать и записывать в файл.

Comment: gecube > у меня с одним #include <fstream> все работает.

Comment: @Roman GoriachevskiyНо вообще по идее не обязано :-) У меня вообще gcc.

Comment: Спасибо тебе ещё раз! Ты меня очень выручил.